# MSTeams: get private chat post edits

Tags: graph, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there a way to retrieve MS Teams private chat posts versions and deletions via Graph API?

My target is to backup 1:1 chats for organisation on daily basis, there are thousands users, i.e. it must work quickly. I am able to pull out what I need with EWS from mailbox, but to let it work it requires **full_access_as_app** permissions (impersonation mechanism), which is not available because of security reasons. Graph API has more granular permission levels (Chat.Read.All, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), so it will work for the main thread, but I don't see a way to get original message version if it was changed.

Comment: @Topa3b.Do you mean how to get the msg which is updated (which was posted and later updated). If this is what you are looking for then you need recapture the updated chat message.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT, yes I need to get msg which was updated. Saying 'recapture', what do you mean? Let's imagine someone posted msg, then changed it 5 times. How can I get all these 5 versions?

Comment: The link in original question died, new is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). The question still opened.